# to remove a row based on the previous row with condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data

```
           date         Price   Signal
14-01-2009 09:55    4819    BB
21-01-2009 09:55    4360    SL
22-01-2009 09:55    4344    BB
29-01-2009 09:55    4484.5  SS
17-02-2009 09:55    4299    SL
25-02-2009 09:55    3984    BB
13-03-2009 09:55    3660    SS
07-07-2009 09:55    7060    SL
```

And I need to arrange it based on Signal like this:

```
     date           Price   Signal
14-01-2009 09:55    4819    BB
21-01-2009 09:55    4360    SL
22-01-2009 09:55    4344    BB
29-01-2009 09:55    4484.5  SS
25-02-2009 09:55    3984    BB
13-03-2009 09:55    3660    SS
```

Can be done in two ways 
1) To delete the rows whenever SL appears after SS 
2) After BB show either SS or SL which ever comes first
Any kind of solution is appreciable.

Comment: You want to follow both ways? Or a single condition is fine?

Comment: I prefer 2nd, though its complicate.

Comment: @davidjones Added an answer with second option. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) to delete the rows whenever SL appears after SS

```
#Get indices of occurrence of SS
inds1 <- which(df$Signal == "SS")

#Get indices of occurrence of SL
inds2 <- which(df$Signal == "SL")

#Check if SS and SL come together
inds3 <- sapply(inds2, function(x) any((x - inds1) == 1))

#Remove the ones which come together
df[-inds2[inds3], ]

#            date  Price Signal
#14-01-2009 09:55 4819.0     BB
#21-01-2009 09:55 4360.0     SL
#22-01-2009 09:55 4344.0     BB
#29-01-2009 09:55 4484.5     SS
#25-02-2009 09:55 3984.0     BB
#13-03-2009 09:55 3660.0     SS
```

---

2) After BB show either SS or SL which ever comes first.

This removes all the rows after first occurrence of "SS" or "SL" for each "BB".

```
df[as.logical(ave(df$Signal, cumsum(df$Signal == "BB"), FUN = function(x) {
   inds <- x %in% c("SS", "SL", "BB")
   replace(inds, -head(which(inds), 2), FALSE)
})), ]


#            date  Price Signal
#14-01-2009 09:55 4819.0     BB
#21-01-2009 09:55 4360.0     SL
#22-01-2009 09:55 4344.0     BB
#29-01-2009 09:55 4484.5     SS
#25-02-2009 09:55 3984.0     BB
#13-03-2009 09:55 3660.0     SS
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this (should be faster too):

```
# convert to data.table
setDT(df)

# create a shifted signal column
df[,shifted_signal := shift(Signal, n=1)]

# create a flag in rows
df[,to_remove := ifelse(Signal == 'SL' & shifted_signal == 'SS', TRUE, FALSE)]

# filter the data
df <- df[to_remove != T][,c('shifted_signal','to_remove') := NULL]    

print(df)

            date  Price Signal
14-01-2009 09:55 4819.0     BB
21-01-2009 09:55 4360.0     SL
22-01-2009 09:55 4344.0     BB
29-01-2009 09:55 4484.5     SS
25-02-2009 09:55 3984.0     BB
13-03-2009 09:55 3660.0     SS
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful as the two ways you have stated are not identical unless 'SL' always comes after 'SS'. Below is one possible solution for the first way:

```
n <- length(df$Signal)
x <- replicate(n, T)

for(i in 1:(n - 1)) {
  if(df$Signal[i] == "SS" & df$Signal[i + 1] == "SL") {
    x[i + 1] <- F
  }
}

df <- df[x, ]
```

Comment: You are right, they are not identical that's why would like to do in both the ways.